# Graph Visualization

Tags: software-development, java, gui, graphs

I'm looking for something similar to Zest wherein I can create data structure and just specify which layout is to be used in order to have a visualization of that graph/ tree data structure available. Could anyone please point out something that fits these requirements? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Graph + Visualisation = [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)? To improve chances for good answers, please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) It would be helpful to explicitely name your requirements – "similar to Zest" is not really sufficient, especially for people not knowing Zest ;)

Comment: There are already several similar questions, such as http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10560/diagram-a-tech-tree.