# Java graph library with visualization on console

Tags: java, data-visualization, graphs

A lot of Java graph libraries, like JGraphT and Graphana, have visualization features for Java AWT or Swing. I'm looking of a graph library which allows to specify vertices and directed edges and then to arrange them before printing them to console resulting in an overview similar to the GUI images.

I realize that the visualization of graphs might be limited, however it's nice to have such output for debugging/tracing purposes and I'm astonished that it hasn't been covered so far.

[Graph Visualization](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10259/graph-visualization) doesn't explain which visualization is needed, it seems to refer to a GUI, not console. Graphviz often comes up when graph and visualization are mentioned, but I didn't find any info whether they or a third-party contributor ever tackeled console visualization. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing doesn't mention console/text UI based drawing.

I'm currently using JGraphT, but it should be easy to transform the graph data into any other structure.

Comment: I don't find a tag for console/text UI related questions. That can't be right, can it? If you have an idea for a tag, please add it.